# Unable to Switch Views with Button in Gluon

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I tried to do follow [How to switch views in Gluon mobile app using javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766717/how-to-switch-views-in-gluon-mobile-app-using-javafx), but it is not switching my views.  Could you advise me on what could be going on, or if there is something I am missing? This is not working all over the project in multiple different instances where I have tried to make a button switch from one view to the other.
Here is an example:

```
  @Override
protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
    appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> getApplication().getDrawer().open()));
    appBar.setTitleText("No Account? Create one! ->");
    appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.PERSON_ADD.button(e -> {
        System.out.println("Switch to secondary view.");
        MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView("SECONDARY_VIEW");
    }));
}
```

For reference, I have no other errors in my code, and all views and transitions through the multi-view sidebar are working perfectly.

Edit: Per request, here is the code where I add the SECONDARY_VIEW to the view factory.

```
package com.mysecondapplication;

import com.mysecondapplication.views.PrimaryView;
import com.mysecondapplication.views.SecondaryView;
import com.mysecondapplication.views.TertiaryView;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.Swatch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MySecondApplication extends MobileApplication {

public static final String PRIMARY_VIEW = HOME_VIEW;
public static final String SECONDARY_VIEW = "Secondary View";
public static final String TERTIARY_VIEW = "Tertiary View";

@Override
public void init() {
    addViewFactory(PRIMARY_VIEW, PrimaryView::new);
    addViewFactory(SECONDARY_VIEW, SecondaryView::new);
    addViewFactory(TERTIARY_VIEW, TertiaryView::new);

    DrawerManager.buildDrawer(this);
}

@Override
public void postInit(Scene scene) {
    Swatch.AMBER.assignTo(scene);

    scene.getStylesheets().add(MySecondApplication.class.getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
    ((Stage) scene.getWindow()).getIcons().add(new Image(MySecondApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png")));
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Edit: instantiating views:

Primary View

```
package com.mysecondapplication.views;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.animation.BounceInRightTransition;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.FloatingActionButton;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Icon;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class PrimaryView extends View {

public PrimaryView() {
    
    Label label = new Label("Hello JavaFX World!");

    Button button = new Button("Change the World!");
    button.setGraphic(new Icon(MaterialDesignIcon.LANGUAGE));
    button.setOnAction(e -> MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView("SECONDARY_VIEW"));
    
    VBox controls = new VBox(15.0, label, button);
    controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    
    setCenter(controls);
}

@Override
protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
    appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> getApplication().getDrawer().open()));
    appBar.setTitleText("No Account? Create one! ->");
    appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.PERSON_ADD.button(e -> {
        System.out.println("Switch to secondary view.");
        MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView("SECONDARY_VIEW");
    }));
}

}
```

Secondary View

```
package com.mysecondapplication.views;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.animation.BounceInRightTransition;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.FloatingActionButton;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Icon;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class SecondaryView extends View {

public SecondaryView() {
    
    Label label = new Label("Hello JavaFX World!");

    Button button = new Button("Change the World!");
    button.setGraphic(new Icon(MaterialDesignIcon.LANGUAGE));
    button.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Hello!"));
    
    VBox controls = new VBox(15.0, label, button);
    controls.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    
    setCenter(controls);
    
}

@Override
protected void updateAppBar(AppBar appBar) {
    appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.MENU.button(e -> getApplication().getDrawer().open()));
    appBar.setTitleText("Have an Account? Log In! ->");
    appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.PEOPLE.button(e -> { 
        System.out.println("Switch to Primary View.");
        MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView("PRIMARY_VIEW");
    }));
}
}
```

Comment: Can you add the part to the question where you create and add `SECONDARY_VIEW` to the view factory?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. My code is readable, complete, and reproducible. I explained the problem and mentioned that it worked. What specifically would you like me to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When switching a view, you're passing a string which does not much the one you used when registering it. To make sure it matches, use the constants already defined in your `MySecondApplication` class

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now. One more related question: how do I call the Primary View, since is does not have a constant that it is defined as. (reference: public static final String PRIMARY_VIEW = HOME_VIEW;)

Comment: Switching to either `PRIMARY_VIEW` or `HOME_VIEW` should work, since they are essentially pointing to the same constant.
You should always use constants to ensure that you never have an issue you described above.